# Increase space between leaves and labels in ggplot2 dendrogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, dendrogram

I need to plot clustering dendrogram using `ggplot2`. To create dendrogram object I use `as.ggdend()` function from the `dendextend` package. However, the space between leaves and labels is very small (see the figure below). Any idea how to increase it?

[image]

The code to reproduce the example is pasted below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dendextend)

## Sample 20 instances of iris dataset
data(iris)
df   <- iris[sample(150, 20), -5]
labs <- paste("Longname_", 1:20, sep = "")
rownames(df) <- labs

## Create dendrogram object
dend <- df %>% dist %>%
  hclust %>% as.dendrogram %>%
  set("labels_cex", 1)
ggd1 <- as.ggdend(dend)

## Plot dendrogram
ggplot(ggd1, horiz = TRUE)
```

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/introduction.html) of `dendextend` package, there is no implementation of changing the space between the leaves. Please refer to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965390/larger-font-and-spacing-between-leaves-in-r-dendrogram) by Tal Galili. I think your best solution here could be `dend <- df %>% dist %>%
  hclust %>% as.dendrogram %>%
  set("labels_cex", 1)%>%
  # hang the leaves (at some height)
  hang.dendrogram(hang_height = .7)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, working on the width and height of your plot can be a simple and valuable solution for your problem.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dendextend)
data(iris)
df   <- iris[sample(150, 20), -5]

## Add blanks before "Longname_"
labs <- paste("  Longname_", 1:20, sep = "")
rownames(df) <- labs

dend <- df %>% dist %>%
  hclust %>% as.dendrogram %>%
  set("labels_cex", 1)
ggd1 <- as.ggdend(dend)

## Resize width and height plotting area
x11(width=10, height=5)
ggplot(ggd1, horiz = TRUE)
```

[image]